# Export media gallery images from magento 1.3

Tags: products-management, upgrade, export

I`m trying to migrate a store from magento 1.3 to 1.8. 
When using "Export All Products" profile in dataflow, the output csv does not contain media_gallery columns and images.

Is there a way to export the gallery images from magento 1.3?

Comment: You should simply upgrade as David Alger has described

Comment: Thats what i did, see my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default import / export does not support working with media gallery's. If I recall correctly, uRapidFlow Pro supports at least importing them, don't know about export though.

My advice: follow the documented upgrade path and upgrade the existing database to move everything to 1.8. Do this in a test environment, record everything which is needed and pre-flight everything before finally doing it on production during a set maintenance window. And finally, before doing it on production, make sure you have a working backup.

Comment: uRapidFlow Pro supports only 1.4+. I Upgraded 1.3 successfully to 1.4.2 and then to 1.8.1.0 by installing a clean magento 1.4.2 and pointed it to the existing 1.3 db, then repeated the process with magento 1.8.1.0

Comment: I am not sure why you can't upgrade directly to 1.8.1?

Comment: @brentwpeterson Because it's not a supported upgrade path. See this page for details: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading#upgrade-path